# Curving the border around image icons in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi I want to curve the border around the image icon as shown in 1 [Image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/503D4.png)but currently I am getting something like in 2[Image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STgAZ.png). Could someone help me with this? Will really appreciate it.

```
<Card className={classes.tabCard} variant="outlined">
                    <CardMedia className={classes.media}></CardMedia>
                    <CardHeader
                        className={classes.cardHeader}
                        avatar={<Avatar className={classes.small}></Avatar>}
                        subheader={
                            <Grid container>
                                <Grid item style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                                    <Typography color="textSecondary" style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
                                        {t("26 March 2021")}
                                    </Typography>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        }
                    ></CardHeader>

media: {
            height: 160,
            backgroundColor: "Red",
            overflow: "visible"
},
small: {
            width: muiTheme.spacing(3),
            height: muiTheme.spacing(3),
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 5,
            border: "3px solid white",
            display: "flex",
            borderRadius: "50% "
        }
```

Comment: Hi Aamir, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [StackOverflow: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. Can you add some code of what you've already tried?

Comment: Ya my bad!! So what I have done is overlay the image on the media and provide a white border around it. I have updated the code in the question. Any ideas?

Comment: Both images look the same to me.

Comment: Ahh there was a mistake. I corrected it. Please check now.